# Big O Notation with the use of methods with different parameters and time

Tags: java

What is the time complexity if faa() takes linear time,

```
for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
    faa(k)
```

or

```
for(int j = 0 ; j < n ;j++)
    faa(j)
```

From what I learned, we are using Big O Notation and time complexity is found by viewing n so both the loops will be O(n) which would be then multiplied by the next line which would give us the answer to the time complexity for both of the problems. Would the answer simply be O(kn) and O(jn) or am I lost? According to my book it says that faa() takes linear time and when it calls upon a parameter faa(k) Big O is O(k) so would j be the same?

Comment: i think `O(kn)` is the correct answer for the first loop, and `O(n^2)` would be correct for the second... (`j` is "just an index/var")

Comment: but `O(kn)` is `O(n)`.... as I understood it (if `k` is non-zero constant)

Comment: Can you clarify which variables are actually changing? The two answers you have (so far) assume opposite things, and thus reach opposite conclusions. Is k a variable, or a constant? (Usually n represents a variable in this kind of questions, and k represents a constant.)

Answer (score 1):

1. With `faa(k)` : the result is `O(n)` as the `faa` is done `n` times in constant time (does not relate on `j`, so `O(kn)` goes to `O(n)` as k does not change)
2. With `faa(j)` : the result is `O(n^2)` as the linear computation is done `n` times and each one goes to `j` but because `j` goes to `n` by approximation we say until `n` for each time,

   - It is better understandable to say it's *quadratic*

Comment: Wouldn’t it be `O(n^2)` since `faa` is `O(j)` for each `j` up to `n`?

Comment: @Michael it depend of the variable, j goes to n, k does not change

Comment: If it's linear, but the input is constant, then it's constant. How long does it take to count to 1000, with one second per number? A constant amount: 1000 seconds.

Comment: @azro well, it all depends on whether you consider K as input, so I suppose we're both sort of right

Answer (score 1):

> According to my book it says that faa() takes linear time and when it
>   calls upon a parameter faa(k) Big O is O(k) so would j be the same?

```
for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
    faa(k)
```

Given an input of `k`  the Big O of `faa(k)` is `O(k)` and it will be executed `n` times , it's perfectly acceptable to say that the Big O complexity for that case is `O(k*n)` .

I disagree with azro.
Even if `k` and `n` are independent there is no indication that `k` is constant, rather the opposite.

They are both variable input important for the calculation of algorithmic complexity.

```
for(int j = 0 ; j < n ;j++)
    faa(j)
```

This is pretty similar to `faa(k)`.

`j` averages to `n/2` , so this will be executed `n * (n/2)` times which can be simplified to `O(N^2)`.

Either way this appears to reach quadratic behavior. So you're not lost at all.

Comment: j is 0-n, so the last paragraph holds for OP's second example. you should make that clearer

Comment: `faa(k)` is independent of `n`, so it is constant time, so that loop is `O(n)` (`O(kn)` == `O(n)` when k is constant)